# Determining a basis of a real subspace of complex matrices, with trace $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $S$ be the $ℝ$-vector subspace of the matrices $A ∈ ℂ^{3x3}$ such that the sum of the elements of its diagonal equals zero. Determine a basis and the dimension of that subspace.

I attach this image where G is the set of generators that I found. Anyway I am not sure if it is correct since the being of complex matrices and the subspace is an $ℝ$-vector subspace I find difficult to see which vectors could determine this subspace and form a base.

[image: I attach this image where G is the set of generators that I found. Anyway I am not sure if it is correct since the being of complex matrices and the subspace is an $ℝ$-vector subspace I find difficult to see which vectors could determine this subspace and form a base.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition of having trace equal to (the complex number) $0$ is a nontrivial complex-linear condition, so the solution set is a complex vector space of dimension $9-1=8$. However, your are asked for its dimension as a real vector space, and then the dimension is $2\times8=16$. For a basis of the real vector space, start with a basis as a complex subspace, then add the complex multiple by$~\mathbf i$ of each basis vector.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply @MarcvanLeeuwen . There is something that is still unclear to me, how do I build matrices that are the basis of this subspace that fulfill the condition that the sum of the elements of its diagonal is zero ?, how do I make sure to find a base that meets that condition?

Comment: what does it mean  a nontrivial complex-linear condition?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is correct.The subspace will be 8 dimensional and as it is a real subspace, all entries will be reals.

Comment: No. Real subspace means subspace over the reals, _not_ real entries.

Comment: Oops! Sorry. Didn't think about that. If it is so, then it will be 16 dimensional. Just replace 1s by iota in the set of generators to get the additional ones. Thanks a lot @MarcvanLeeuwen for the correction.